# AjaxControlToolkit.FilteredTextBoxExtender

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using Visual Studio 2008, .NET Framework 3.5
I am also using the latest version of AjaxControlToolkit available for .NET Framework 3.5

When using the FilteredTextBoxExtender on a Textbox Control shown in code below, I have set the filter to be upper-case only. The filter does work in terms of preventing the user from entering lower-case letters, but when I press letters from P - Z, the letter actually gets entered in and then erased, where as when I type letters from A - O, the letter is not entered at all. I am wondering why there is the inconsistency.

My problem is that, for my own reasons, I need it so that when I highlight a single character and change the character, if it is not upper-case, the current character should remain (which works when I type characters between A - O), however, the current character actually gets deleted when I type a character between P - Z.

Question:
Is there workaround prevent characters P - Z from displaying altogether?

Any help would be great.
Thank you

To confirm is not my own code's issue, I found a demo link that also demonstrate the same issue:
http://www.aspsnippets.com/Demos/272/

```
AjaxControlToolkit.FilteredTextBoxExtender ftbe = new                   AjaxControlToolkit.FilteredTextBoxExtender();
ftbe.ID = "ftbe";
ftbe.TargetControlID = "textboxID";
ftbe.FilterType = AjaxControlToolkit.FilterTypes.UppercaseLetters;
ftbe.FilterMode = AjaxControlToolkit.FilterModes.ValidChars;
form1.Controls.Add(ftbe);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set characters in [ValidChars](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/ajaxcontroltoolkitsamplesite/filteredtextbox/filteredtextbox.aspx) to allow specific characters only.

> **InvalidChars**. If set to InvalidChars, FilterType must be set to
>   Custom; if set to ValidChars, FilterType must contain Custom.

```
var ftbe = new FilteredTextBoxExtender();
ftbe.ID = "ftbe";
ftbe.TargetControlID = textBox.ID;
ftbe.FilterType = FilterTypes.Custom; // ** Custom **
ftbe.FilterMode = FilterModes.ValidChars;
ftbe.ValidChars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO"; // Allow uppercase A to O only.
```

Comment: Thanks for the response sir, let say I set valid input as Numeric only. If you go to the demo site below and type in A-O, it will not input the character, but if you type P-Z, it will input the character and then delete it. I need P-Z to not input at all. I am also wondering why the inconsistency: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Demos/272/